# import asgi_redis: ImportError: No module named _compat

Tags: django, heroku, redis, django-channels

I can import asgi_redis on my local server fine but I get the error in the title when i try to import asgi_redis on my production server (heroku, using heroku run bash). Both have the same version of asgi_redis.

Here is the full traceback:

```
>>> import asgi_redis
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/asgi_redis/__init__.py", line 1
, in <module>
    from .core import RedisChannelLayer
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/asgi_redis/core.py", line 10, i
n <module>
    from redis._compat import b
ImportError: No module named _compat
```

Does anyone know what is going on here? Thanks in advance.
I also have redis installed, redis 2.6.0, FWIW

Answer (score 0):

local server had latest redis, production did not. upgraded redis on production and error is gone